# How to exit a window procedure inside of a dll injected into a process?

Tags: c++, winapi, hook

I have created a dummy window inside of my dll as an `IPC` method:

Window procedure:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
        case WM_COPYDATA:
        {
          //....
        }
        case WM_DESTROY:
        case WM_QUIT:
            OutputDebugString(L"WM_QUIT");
            PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}


int Main(LPCWSTR dummy_class_name)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc{};
    //HWND dummy_hwnd;
    MSG Msg;

    wc.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style         = 0;
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra    = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra    = 0;
    wc.hInstance     = 0;
    wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wc.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = dummy_class_name;
    wc.hIconSm       = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);


    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Window Registration Failed!", L"Error!",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    dummy_hwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_LEFT, // this is the default
                        dummy_class_name, // the name of the class, as passed to the RegisterClass function
                        NULL, //  Title
                        0,    //  dwFlags, in our case this really doesn't matter
                        0,    //  X 
                        0,    //  Y 
                        0,    //  W 
                        0,    //  H 
                        HWND_MESSAGE , //the most important flag! Creates a message-only window
                        0,    //  hMenu 
                        0 ,   //  hInstance this function gets the instance handle of the current app
                        0     //  lpParam 
    );

    if(dummy_hwnd == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Window Creation Failed!", L"Error!",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(dummy_hwnd, SW_SHOW);
    UpdateWindow(dummy_hwnd);

    while(GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    }
    return 0; // Msg.wParam;
}
```

Im initializing the window procedure on a secondary thread:

```
class std::future<void> thread;

void Foo() {
    // ...
    thread = std::async(std::launch::async, [dummy_class_name]
    { Main(dummy_class_name); });
}
```

However, when the process i'm hooking with the dll 'exits' it remains 'dormant'.
When i dont call the `Foo` function, it does exit completely.

I tried to hook the target process function `ExitCode` and call the WndProc function with `WM_QUIT`, `WM_DESTROY` it does receive the messages but the process still remains open.

```
void ExitProcess_Hook(UINT uExitCode)
{
    OutputDebugString(L"\nExitProcess_Hook!");

    //PostMessageW(dummy_hwnd, WM_DESTROY, 0, 0);
    WndProc(dummy_hwnd, WM_DESTROY, 0, 0);

    return ExitProcess(uExitCode);
}
```

What im missing?

Comment: Try calling `TerminateProcess` - _"..Therefore, if you do not know the state of all threads in your process, it is better to call TerminateProcess than ExitProcess. ..."_ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-exitprocess

Comment: @RichardCritten thank you, TerminateProcess does work. Could you make it as an answer?

Comment: @RichardCritten *if you do not know the state of all threads in your process* - but this is almost always. but not mean that need call `TerminateProcess`.  if process hung inside ExitProcess  - this mean error in codding. and use `TerminateProcess` - fast solution, instead research, understand and fix errors

Comment: You should post a minimal reproducing project somewhere. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

One thing you are missing is that the window procedure shouldn't ever actually see a WM_QUIT message. GetMessage returns 0 if the retrieved message is WM_QUIT and that should exit the message loop before DispatchMessage is called.

The other thing you are missing is that window message queues are thread-based, so even if you did a `PostQuitMessage(0);` from some other message in your message-only window's WindowProc that quit message wouldn't go to the process' main message loop. You could do `PostThreadMessage(dwMainThreadID, WM_QUIT, 0, 0);` (where dwMainThreadID is the result of `GetCurrentThreadId()` at the time you are calling std::async and that would go to the process' UI thread message queue.

Comment: " at the time you are calling std::async" Do you mean to call `GetCurrentThreadId()` from inside of `Main`? and then use it with `PostThreadMessage(dwMainThreadID, WM_QUIT, 0, 0);`

Comment: I did it, the process remains open. After calling for `PostThreadMessage(dwMainThreadID, WM_QUIT, 0, 0);` i tried: `HWND hwnd = FindWindowExW(HWND_MESSAGE, NULL, L"MyClass", NULL);` and it have found her `hwnd` so it did not received the WM_QUIT message?

Comment: @Razec - your problem at all not here. all threads killed when `ExitProcess` called, except thread which call `ExitProcess`. no sense post something to window - it thread already killed and nodody receive message (and window destroyed too). faster of all you hang in destructor of global objects. you need look call stack at the first

Comment: @RbMm I mean when closing the app which the dll is injected, why it would kill the thread wheres the window procedure? The window is not destroyed, as I said in my previous comment I still could find the window with `FindWindow`.

Comment: @Razec all threads in process is killed if ExitProcess called.(except caller). post call stack

Comment: @RbMm i have no idea which call stack you are reffering to, do you mean this? https://i.imgur.com/IkycnZd.png

Comment: @Razec you think something visible in *this* ? post normal call stack with symbols

Comment: I dont have the pdb for the process im hooking.

Comment: @Razec - not need pdb for exe. but need pdb for your dll and system dlls

Comment: @RbMm well, thats all i can see in the callstack of windbg, the dll pdb is in the same folder.

Comment: @Razec - i dont know what you view. but i view nothing

Comment: @RbMm this is the data i can see on windbg callstack, https://i.imgur.com/NgZ41Rt.gif
i dont understand "post normall call stack with symbols" the pdb is on the folder, this is all the data its loading. If im doing something wrong be more specific, i dont know how to debug things as you're requesting.

Comment: @Razec - and what you whant ? `ZwTerminateProcess` with `NtCurrentProcess()` is called. this is all. you think good look on anumated gif ?

Comment: Not trying to be rude but "what I think" is that you need to learn how to write correctly because I don't understand almost anything you say, and about "what I want" is described in the title and in the post.

Comment: [Why is there a special PostQuitMessage function?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20051104-33/?p=33453)

Comment: @IInspectable : PostQuitMessage comes from win16 which did not support multiple threads in a single process. I don't know if win16 had anything akin to PostThreadMessage (that is, a message not targeted at a particular HWND).

Comment: @Razec image which you post clear show that process is terminated, despite you say that not